# NodeJS - How to force a function to run on a specific worker id only in a cluster?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently running my Express Node Application in cluster mode. How would I force a function to run only in a specific PID? And other PIDs won't run the same function?

EDIT:

It depends on the user input. Let's say if I receive an input of John, I will run this function on PID 01 only. If I receive Doe, I will run the function on PID 02 only. So everytime I receive an input John, it will always run on PID 01.

Answer (score 1):

How about just `if (process.pid === YOUR_TARGET_PID) { theFunction(); }` with `process` built-in module?

Comment: I believe there are some missing pieces in my question, I already updated the question. :)